# Triggering from child to change the store does not updates the store

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vuex

Parent File html

```
<div v-if="!refresh" class="c-focus-mode">
  <div class="c-focus-mode__container">
    <div class="c-focus-mode__container-left">
      <slide-card
        focus
        hideBottom
        :slideID="slideID"
        :index="orderIndex"
        :totalCount="5"
        :totalDuration="10"
        :isMobile="false"
      >
// Does not work (1)
      <template v-slot:prevSlideBtnLeft>
        <app-button
          v-if="!prevInvalid"
          type="circular"
          class="c-slide-card-preview__btn c-slide-card-preview__btn--prev"
          @click="goToSlide(-1)"
          ><app-icon name="chevron-left"></app-icon>
        </app-button>
      </template>
      <template v-slot:nextSlideBtnRight>
        <app-button
          v-if="!nextInvalid"
          type="circular"
          class="c-slide-card-preview__btn c-slide-card-preview__btn--next"
          @click="goToSlide(1)"
          ><app-icon name="chevron-right"></app-icon>
        </app-button>
      </template>
      </slide-card>
// Works below (2)
      <div
        class="c-focus-mode__container-left-navigation"
        :class="{['c-focus-mode__container-left-navigation--no-prev']: prevInvalid}"
      >
      <app-button
        v-if="!prevInvalid"
        type="circular"
        class="c-slide-card-preview__btn c-slide-card-preview__btn--prev"
        @click="goToSlide(-1)"
        ><app-icon name="chevron-left"></app-icon>
      </app-button>
      <app-button
        v-if="!nextInvalid"
        type="circular"
        class="c-slide-card-preview__btn c-slide-card-preview__btn--next"
        @click="goToSlide(1)"
        ><app-icon name="chevron-right"></app-icon>
      </app-button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <slide-card
      focus
      hideTop
      :slideID="slideID"
      :index="orderIndex"
      :totalCount="5"
      :totalDuration="10"
      :isMobile="false"
    >
    </slide-card>
  </div>
</div>
```

Functions called by the app-button components

```
  public goToSlide(increment) {
    const newIndex = this.orderIndex + increment;
    if (newIndex < 0 || newIndex >= this.deckSlides.length) {
      return;
    }
    this.setActiveSlide(newIndex);
  }

  private setActiveSlide(index) {
    this.slideIndex = index + 1;
    const { deckID, ID: slideID } = this.deckSlides[index];

    if (deckID && slideID) {
      this.$store.dispatch('deck/setActiveSlides', { deckID, slideID });
      history.replaceState({}, null, `/d/${this.deckID}/edit/focus/${index + 1}`);
    }
  }
```

When goToSlide is called from the buttons at "Works below (2)", store is updated successfully, but when the same function is called from the buttons at "Does not work (1)", store is not updated. The same thing happens when I try to emit an action from slide-card to trigger goToSlide function in the parent.

Comment: does the click handler get triggered at all?

Comment: It does gets triggered

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is that you are trying to call the method from within the slot and by default slot doesn't have access to data and methods that are defined in the parent component.

what you can do is that you should provide access to the method for slot which is called 'scoped slots' and here is the documentation link for it:

[scoped slots in vue](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-slots.html#Scoped-Slots)

also this answer might help:

[call method from slot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44103424/call-method-from-component-inside-components-slot-slot)

Comment: Thank you for you answer but I have access to the method, it does get triggered. Unfortunately my problem is that the store is not being updated when the parent function is called. Even if I don't use scope and solve it with emitting an event, I do come across the same problem.